# Method that takes a string text and returns the sum of identified integers

Tags: java

The method should take a string text, identify all the integers in the string, and return the sum of the identified integers.

For example, the string "a2.05h34-9fmq26" contains the integers 2, 5 (05), 34, -9, and 26, so the method should return 58. I have following code so far:

```
public static int sumOfIntegers(String text) {
       int sum = 0;

       for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
           if(Character.isDigit(text.charAt(i)))
               sum = sum + Character.getNumericValue(text.charAt(i));
       }
       return sum;
}
```

So far I can sum all positive integers, but what I'm unsure of is how to subtract negative integers from the sum.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to find the group of digits:

```
String s = "a2.05h34-9fmq26";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(s);

int result = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    result += Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
}

System.out.println(result);
```

**Output**

```
58
```

The pattern `-?\d+` means match a group of one or more digits that may be preceded by a hyphen. More about [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) can be found in the docs.

Comment: The solution works of course. But the OP is beginner and will not learn how to approach the the problem, will not learn how to think. That's why your answer is not helpful.

Comment: I don't think 2.05 is an integer.

Comment: @WJS In the question 2 and 05 are treated as two different numbers

Comment: You're right.  Another conflict between title and the rest.

Comment: @mentallurg  As far as answers not being helpful or spoon feeding solutions, that ship has sailed long ago.  That's why forums are better for helping new folks as you can maintain a conversation with them.  I was told comments weren't the place for that.

Comment: @WJS: Comments - sure, not the best place. But a solution that considers the level of the OP - this is the good place.

Comment: Math should be done with `int` values, not java.lang.Integer instances that need to be frequently boxed and unboxed.

Answer (score 0):

It should be apparent that you cannot obtain a number like 34 if you sum the digits one at a time.  You will need to keep track of the consecutive digits you have encountered, and add them to the sum only when you encounter a non-digit or the end of the string.

```
int sum = 0;

int currentValue = 0;
boolean negative = false;

for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    char c = text.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        int digitValue = Character.getNumericValue(text.charAt(i));

        currentValue = currentValue * 10;

        if (negative) {
            currentValue = currentValue - digitValue;
        } else {
            currentValue = currentValue + digitValue;
        }
    } else {
        sum = sum + currentValue;
        currentValue = 0;
        negative = (c == '-');
    }
}

sum = sum + currentValue;

return sum;
```